# How to write read() with poll() functionality in kernel for tty driver?

Tags: c, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, tty

In my driver module data is coming in callback function. 
I want to add data to read callback but not able to find read callback in tty structure

Comment: We are neither a coding nor a tutoring service. What is your **specific** problem with your existing code?

Comment: Also, there is [LDD3](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), which goes fairly deep into the details of writing Linux kernel drivers; OP should take a look at the scull example driver in particular, and the char driver chapters in general. As of 2017-09-10, LDD4 hasn't been published yet.

Comment: I mean to say I am not able to find a read callback in tty structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no read callback. The tty core buffers the data received by the tty drivers in a structure called struct tty_flip_buffer. Read [Chapter 18](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch18.pdf) of LDD3